# I'm writing a calendar program in java, but besides oct 2015 the months dont match, i need help please

Tags: java, calendar

So basicaly, everything works like it should. But the main thing that should be correct, which is the date, is wrong, so far for october 2015 it is correct but for some reason i cannot detect, the other months i have tried so far are incorrect when compared to the calendar in my computer.
Here is my program, maybe you have some valid input to help me with these issues.

```
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        int month = 0;
        int s = getDaysIn(month, year);
        return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }

    public static int getDaysIn(int month, int year) {
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                return 31;
            case 2:
                if (isLeapYear(month)) {
                    return 29;
                } else {
                    return 28;
                }
            case 3:
                return 31;
            case 4:
                return 30;
            case 5:
                return 31;
            case 6:
                return 30;
            case 7:
                return 31;
            case 8:
                return 31;
            case 9:
                return 30;
            case 10:
                return 31;
            case 11:
                return 30;
            case 12:
                return 31;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    public static String getMonthName(int month) {
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                return "January";
            case 2:
                return "February";
            case 3:
                return "March";
            case 4:
                return "April";
            case 5:
                return "May";
            case 6:
                return "June";
            case 7:
                return "July";
            case 8:
                return "August";
            case 9:
                return "September";
            case 10:
                return "October";
            case 11:
                return "November";
            case 12:
                return "December";
            default:
                return "Invalid month.";
            }
        }

    public static int getStartDay(int month, int year) {
        int days = 0;

        for (int i = 1900; i < year; i++) {
            days = days + 365;
            if (isLeapYear(i)) {
                days = days + 1;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) {
            days = days + getDaysIn(month, year);
        }
        int startday = (days + 1) % 7 + 2;
        return startday;
    }

    public static void displayCalendar(int month, int year) {
        String monthName = getMonthName(month);
        int startDay = getStartDay(month, year);
        int monthDays = getDaysIn(month, year);

        System.out.println("   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri       Sat");
        int weekDay = startDay - 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < startDay; i = i + 1) {
            System.out.print("      ");
        }
        for (int x = 1; x <= monthDays; x++) {
            weekDay = weekDay + 1;
            if (weekDay > 7) {
                System.out.println();
                weekDay = 1;
            }
            System.out.format("   %3d", x);
        }
        if (weekDay > 7) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What output do you expect / what output do you get? Also `isLeapYear(month)` should probably be `isLeapYear(year)`...

Comment: Why are you recreating the wheel?

Comment: the question is why the calculation of days is wrong, since i get the incorrect number for the specific month i input

Comment: http://www.joda.org/ use a well established API for date and time management. Don't recreate the wheel. If you want to know why you shouldn't recreate the wheel here's a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: @YaWang , seems like a HW assignment, I had to do the same thing in college. A description stating it's an assignment would be helpful. That way people can provide better help, instead of links to existing API.

Comment: @YaWang this is introductory, I had to "reinvent" the wheel plenty of times for introductory classes.  Recoded everything from sorting algorithms to path finding algorithms. It helped me gain a solid understanding of fundamentals. It's not about reinventing the wheel. It's about understanding how the wheel came to be.

Comment: yes, i agree, and yes it is a hw assigment, but with little reference or previous explanations...it is hard to do bymyself and also see the errors, i had developed the code bymyself so i m not asking to write it for me, but i have been trying to fix this for the last 4 days and where there were some things i conquered there are others that still affect the code

Comment: I'll check and comeback

Comment: Start with testing your getStartDay function. Ignore the entire output of calendar page, just make sure that the start day for a few months comes out correctly.

Comment: @Ceelos I understand your opinion. It's like learning history... which may also be useless. In terms of algorithms each implementation is different google is enough to teach you about the method you didn't need classes for that. I will not comment anymore we are too off topic. OP don't use your code for practical purposes and always do research first before writing code is my point.

Comment: @YaWang you deleted your snarky comment :)

Comment: can somebody tell me why i keep getting the incorrect start day, i tried several things but still get the wrong data....please help me

Comment: The second loop inside `getStartDay` is repeatedly passing the same month to the `getDaysIn` method.

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe what result you looking for? I see this "days = days + 365;" days will just keep adding up... so eventually its 365*(1900-inputyear)

Comment: i am looking for the right calendar when year 1900 to 2099 is input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getStartDay is actually where your error lays :

```
    for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) {
        days = days + getDaysIn(month, year);
    }
    int startday = (days + 1) % 7 + 2;
    return startday;
```

Should be replaced with :

```
    for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) {
        days = days + getDaysIn(i, year);
    }
    int startday = (days % 7) + 2;
    return startday;
```

There is a minor problem with your loop as you see.

You should have had used your incrementor `i` in your `getDaysIn` calls to count the days from the begin of the year until the month you want to display.

---

Second error is here :

```
    int startday = (days + 1) % 7 + 2;
```

The logic behind this expression is still a mystery for me.

Let's break this off with a concrete **example** :

Let's say we want to display ***FEB 1900***. Easy to do because we start at the begin of ***JAN 1900*** so we can count the days easily (31 days in january so `days` = 31)

Which result will the first expression return?

```
= (31 + 1) % 7 + 2
= 32 % 7 + 2    
= 4 + 2    
= 6
```

Because day `1` in your logic is SUNDAY, day `6` is FRIDAY.

Let's check it out :

[image: NotReallyTheExpectedResult]

Not really the expected result right?

I see one more problem with this method.

Let's imagine `days = 33` (this will never happens but we need this example here).

```
= (33 + 1) % 7 + 2
= 34 % 7 + 2
= 6 + 2
= 8
```

What would the 8th day of the week be?

---

The explanation of the correct answer is the following :

```
(days % 7) + 2
```

`days % 7` gives us the value of the last day of the following month when weeks begin with MONDAY.

To this value, we add 2 :

- 1 to have the beginning day of the wanted month.
- 1 because our calendar begins with sunday and we'll have to slide our days on the calendar view.

---

Here is the full code (that I also modified a bit to make it more compact) :

```
    public class Calendar{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // INSERT YOUR TESTS HERE
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }

    public static int getDaysIn(int month, int year) {
        switch (month) {
            case 1 : case 3 : case 5 : case 7 : case 8 : case 10 : case 12 :
                return 31; 
            case 4 : case 6 : case 9 : case 11 :
                return 30; 
            case 2:
                return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28; 
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }

    public static String getMonthName(int month) {
        String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        return month <= 12 && month > 0 ? months[month - 1] : "Invalid month";
    }

    public static int getStartDay(int month, int year) {
        int days = 0;

        for (int i = 1900; i < year; i++) {
            days += 365;
            if (isLeapYear(i)) {
                days = days + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) {
            days = days + getDaysIn(i, year);
        }
        int startday = (days % 7) + 2;
        return startday;
    }

    public static void displayCalendar(int month, int year) {
        String monthName = getMonthName(month);
        int startDay = getStartDay(month, year);
        int monthDays = getDaysIn(month, year);

        System.out.println("   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat");
        int weekDay = startDay - 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < startDay; i = i + 1) {
            System.out.print("      ");
        }
        for (int x = 1; x <= monthDays; x++) {
            weekDay = weekDay + 1;
            if (weekDay > 7) {
                System.out.println();
                weekDay = 1;
            }
            System.out.format("   %3d", x);
        }
        if (weekDay > 7) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT**

You should try to write something in your main method if nothing displays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
        System.out.println(getMonthName(i+1) + " " + (2010 + i));
        displayCalendar(i+1, 2010 + i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Gives the following output :

```
    January 2010
   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
                                   1     2
     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
    10    11    12    13    14    15    16
    17    18    19    20    21    22    23
    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
    31
February 2011
   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
                 1     2     3     4     5
     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
    13    14    15    16    17    18    19
    20    21    22    23    24    25    26
    27    28
March 2012
   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
                             1     2     3
     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
    18    19    20    21    22    23    24
    25    26    27    28    29    30    31
April 2013
   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
           1     2     3     4     5     6
     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
    28    29    30
May 2014
   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
                             1     2     3
     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
    18    19    20    21    22    23    24
    25    26    27    28    29    30    31
```

Comment: thanks, i have applied the fixes but the full code you posted, produces no output, also i changed the corrections on my program but still unlucky, i still get for ex that nov starts a sunday]

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe I edited my answer. Do not forget to accept.